# How to create a pointed div when a link is clicked in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

"I want to create a gallery(in right panel) with the link on the left panel. If I'm going to click the link on the left panel, gallery on the right should change dynamically depending on what is clicked by the user, AND there should have  a **POINTED DIV** that will point to the current link which was clicked".

This is the scenario that I am doing but I dont know how to do this. Do you have any idea or links for me to refer?

Thanks,

This is my code:

```
 <div class="left-panel">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#link1" class="active">Link1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#link2">Link2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#link3">Link3</a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="right-panel">
    <!-- Output should be displayed here-->
     <img src="src1.jpg"/>
     <img src="src2.jpg"/>
     <img src="src3.jpg"/>
  </div>
```

Comment: You mean [(this)](http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Lt7Rz/) or [(this)](http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/D8N5E/1/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
var anchors = $('.left-panel a');

anchors.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.right-panel img').hide().eq(anchors.index(this)).show();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ASjJ9/2/)